# jQuery infinitescroll, kaminari, and Rails 4. Infinitescroll triggering on another page. Not after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, infinite-scroll, kaminari

Running into a weird behaviour using Paul Irish's [infinitescroll](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/blob/master/Readme.md) plugin with [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/wiki/How-To%3a-Create-Infinite-Scrolling-with-jQuery) and rails 4. I've followed the example given on kaminari's wiki, and have the following code:

```
$(document).ready ->
    $("#activities .activityBox").infinitescroll
        navSelector: "ul.pagination"
        nextSelector: "ul.pagination a[rel=next]"
        itemSelector: "#activities div.activityBox"
```

The `infinitescroll` plugin works perfectly on `pages#home` where the `div#activities` element is located. What's not working as intended however is that the plugin is still firing AFTER I navigate away from `pages#home`.

For instance, I would be browsing on `pages#home`. I'd click a link to `Tags#index`. When I scroll to the bottom of `Tags#index`, infinitescroll would fetch and render the next batch of activities. The behaviour stops after refreshing the page with the browser.

How do I get infinitescroll to fire only when `div#activities` is present?

Comment: What if you change `$("div#activities .activityBox")` to `$("#activities")`? And why you added `div`, it's `id` can only be one on page.

Comment: Didnt work. Behaviour remains unchanged. I tried the GarberIrish method to limit the script to page#home. Didn't work as well.

Comment: Do you use `turbolinks`? I think in that post assumes, that file `post.coffee` only work on that page. If you have turbo, or your code just in `application.js.coffee` it work anyway. It's a bug of course anyway, but it would be easy to locate the problem.

Comment: Yes i do use turbolinks. and i think that's the key to the problem. I tried foo.infinitescroll if foo.length but the problem remains.

Comment: Well, seems like a bug. You should post it on issue tracker of kaminari, it has good support, maybe they help faster. Infinite-scroll has really bad support (almost 100 open issues), but both issue trackers has nothing about turbolinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of experimentation, I've decided to abandon the jquery.infinitescroll plugin.

Ryan Bates' implementation [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/114-endless-page-revised) works fine, doesn't require an external plugin, and is compatible with turbolinks.

Comment: I can't view the link you've posted, please share your solution in code or words..